# how to add a series of powers such that f(x) = 1^1.5 + 2^1.5 + 3^1.5... + x^1.5 in a more efficient fashion

Tags: numerical-methods, exponentiation

I am working on a programming project where I am working with the equation $$f(x) = 1^{1.5} + 2^{1.5} + 3^{1.5} + \cdots + x^{1.5},$$ which I am calculating using that formula. Unfortunately this has started slowing down my program when working with larger values of $x$. I was wondering if it were possible to simplify this equation in a way such that a computer could solve it in a much faster manner. Thank-you in advance.

Comment: How large is the $x$ that makes a problem?  What accuracy can you accept?  If $x$ is large you can ignore the smaller terms because they do not contribute within the accuracy you require.  Alternately you can convert the sum to an integral, which makes it very fast and the error is well bounded.  What have you tried?  Is this news to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a nice closed-form expression for your sum in terms of elementary functions, but since you're working in the context of programming presumably you need only an approximate answer. (To give a more complete answer than below it would be useful to know what kind of accuracy you require.)

Computing a series representation for the sum about $n = \infty$ gives
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i^{3 / 2} = \underbrace{\frac{2}{5} n^{5 / 2} + \frac{1}{2} n^{3 / 2} + \frac{1}{8} n^{1 / 2} + \zeta\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}_{h(n)} + O\left(n^{-3 /2}\right),$$
and truncating the series after the constant term, $\zeta\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right) = -0.02548520189\ldots$, yields a (comparatively computationally cheap) function $h(n)$ that gives good approximations even for small $n$:

$$\begin{array}{rrrr}
n & \sum_{i = 1}^n i^{3 / 2} & h(n) & \epsilon \\
\hline
1 & 1\phantom{.82824675\ldots} & 0.99951479\ldots & \approx 5 \cdot 10^{-4} \\
2 &  3.82842712\ldots & 3.82824675\ldots & \approx 9 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
4 & 17.02457955\ldots & 17.02451480\ldots & \approx 2 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
8 & 84.04953407\ldots & 84.04951109\ldots & \approx 3 \cdot 10^{-6} \\
\end{array} .$$
Here the column labeled $\epsilon$ gives (the absolute value of) the relative error.
If you need greater accuracy, you can add to $h(n)$ additional terms from the series. For example, if we include the next term, $\frac{1}{1920} n^{-3/2}$, the relative error for $n = 8$ is $\approx 4 \cdot 10^{-9}$.

**Remark** The integral inequalities
$$\int_0^{n - 1} x^{3 / 2} \,dx \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n i^{3 / 2} \leq \int_1^n x^{3 / 2} \,dx ,$$ together immediately give $$\sum_{i = 1}^n i^{3 / 2} = \frac{2}{5} n^{5 / 2} + O(n^{3 / 2}),$$ that is, the leading term of the series.

Answer (score 3):

Using generalized harmonic numbers $$S_x=\sum_{n=1}^x n^{\frac 32}=H_x^{\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ Using asymptotics

$$S_x=\frac{2 x^{5/2}}{5}\Bigg[
1+\frac{5}{4 x}+\frac{5}{16 x^2}+\frac{5\zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2x^{\frac 52}} +\frac{1}{768 x^4}-\frac{5}{43008 x^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Bigg]$$ Trying with $x=123456789$ the absolute error is $5.75 \times 10^{-50}$
and the relative error is  $8.48 \times 10^{-70}$

**Edit**

If $x$ is really large, a good approximation is
$$S_x=\frac {8(x+1)}{5(4x-1)}x^{5/2}$$ whose error is $\frac{5\zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2x^{\frac 52}}$.

If $x \geq 35$, the absolute relative error is smaller then $0.001$%.